# How come GetListItems filtering on a field's equality to a value fetches this field's value as undefined/null

Tags: caml-query, 2007, web-services

I think I found a bug. Please share if you know more about it.

I use GetListItems operation to fetch items to display on an ajaxified form. Just an hour ago everything was fine, but now when I query the list with

```
<Eq><FieldRef Name='Some/Field'><Value Type='Lookup'>Value</Value></Eq>
```

The relevant items show up in the result set. But the values for 'Some/Field' (yes there is a slash in the displayname) are displayed as null. The field was never renamed.

What is it? How can I fix?

Comment: Are you using SPServices or some other method?

Comment: I spotted the error when I used SPServices and then confirmed using u2u CAML Query Builder

Answer (score 1):

If the display Name of your field contains a slash and never been modified then I believe you caml should look like this

```
<Eq><FieldRef Name='Some_x002f_Field'><Value Type='Lookup'>Value</Value></Eq>
```

Notice the encoded slash (_x002f_).

Comment: Actually, the slash is only in displayname. Iternal is all encoded as hell: _x0423__x0432..._x04

Comment: And of course that CAML query has the proper InternalName substituted - once by hand and once by u2uCamlQueryBuilder

Comment: I have tried to recreate your problem but it seems to be working fine for me.
Added a column with a slash and the only way that I got to fail is if don't encode the slash.
You said that the internal is encoded but on you CAML query you are using the display ? you should be using the internal in stead.